# Driver.current_url not reflecting the opening of a link- selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

After using Selenium to log in to LinkedIn, I'm trying to navigate to the jobs page using the following:

```
jobs = driver.find_element(
    By.XPATH, '//*[@id="global-nav"]/div/nav/ul/li[3]/a')

jobs.click()

job_src = driver.page_source
print(driver.current_url)
```

The above returns: https://www.linkedin.com/feed/
However, looking at the browser that selenium opens up, it looks as though https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/? is clicked on.

Is my XPATH wrong? I copied it from Chrome Dev tools.

From there, I'm trying to scrape the job titles using :

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(job_src, 'html.parser')
job_list_html = soup.select('.job-card-list__title')


for job in job_list_html:
    print(job.get_text())
```

But all that's returned is an empty list.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are running into is that you need to wait until the page has loaded. Here is my suggestion.

First after you log in you can navigate directly to the job list URL. This is likely to be less fragile than using the XPath:

```
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/collections/recommended/')
```

The following is the most important piece you are missing:

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'job-card-list__title')))
```

You can look into other wait commands [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html), but the above appeared to work for me.

Next, I noticed that this only lists a few jobs since the rest are dynamically loaded when you scroll. What I did is simulated the scrolling with:

```
driver.execute_script('res = document.querySelector("#main > div > section.scaffold-layout__list > div"); res.scrollTo(0, res.scrollHeight)') 
time.sleep(2)
```

The sleep of 2 seconds is needed again to give time for that to execute before you get the source.

With that wait and the scroll, your code for getting the list of job names works.

```
job_src = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(job_src, 'html.parser')
job_list_html = soup.select('.job-card-list__title')
print(len(job_list_html))
for job in job_list_html:
    print(job.get_text())
```

You may notice that the job list is paginated, so this code will only get the first page of jobs, but hopefully this gets you on the right track.

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was looking for. I was messing with various different XPaths and none seemed to work for the Jobs link. However, I was able to open up other pages on LinkedIn. Do you have any idea why my original XPath wasn't working? Thanks DevLan!

Comment: From your description, it sounds like your XPath was correct. It sounds like https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/ was clicked successfully, but it printed the previous URL (https://www.linkedin.com/feed/) before loading the new URL.

Comment: The jobs URL only lists a couple of jobs though, then there is a button to "show all". Once you are logged in through, it is easier to go straight to the URL with `get`, rather than clicking two links.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, it's definitely easier to go straight to the URL. Thanks for the help— much appreciated.

Comment: I've found that after adding your scrolling script (and even after adding different logic) selenium continues to scrape the first 4-5 job posts on the page, scroll to the bottom of the first page, and scrape the last 2-3 job posts. In the end, I'm only scraping 7-9 job posts. Do you know how to make this scrolling incremental so I can scrape > scroll > scrape > scroll, until I've reached the bottom of the page?

Comment: You could try updating the second argument of the `scrollTo` method. Right now this `res.scrollTo(0, res.scrollHeight)` is scrolling to the maximum height, you could try scrolling by a fixed amount, get the job titles and repeat until you reach `res.scrollHeight`. I would also include some logic to remove duplicate job titles, that way you don't need to find the exact correct number of pixels to scroll.